# Is it safe to ignore the return value of Popen?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I need that my python (2.7) program starts a sub-process and that it continues its processing while the child process is running. So I don’t want the main program to wait for the sub-process termination.

This is apparently achieved with Popen that returns a class object.

Is it safe to ignore the return value of Popen ?

Does the garbage collector delete the popen object ? Is the object garbage collected after the sub-process terminated ?

I can’t answer these questions with the python documentation.

Note that I’m using python 2.7 because of constrains I have no control on.

Answer (score 2):

On Unix-like systems, failing to `wait()` on children creates zombies. This is a problem because you are polluting and eventually exhausting your process table.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_(system_call)

If you want to kill your child process when your program finishes, do that. That's precisely why you need to save the result from `Popen()`.

```py
child = Popen(['sleep', '1234567890'])
# ... code happens ...
child.kill()
child.wait()
```

Just to reiterate, the Python object returned by `Popen()` is of course going to go away when Python goes away; the problem is that you also need to clean up the actual OS process which it represents.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This is exactly what I wanted to avoid. I don’t want the need to call `child.kill()`. I guess I need to create a detached process then.

Comment: FWIW unless you spawn subprocesses in a loop in a long-lived process, once the parent dies the children will get re-parented to PID1 which will reap its zombies, so wait-ing on children is hardly a requirement.

Comment: Also killing children does not wait() them, so it specifically *creates* zombies.

Comment: @Masklinn Thanks, added the missing `wait()` (meant to look it up but got distracted).